# Third party C static library: Add -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

Tags: c, gcc, arm, static-libraries

I am in the situation to have a c static library (compiled with arm-gcc), which is provided by a third party. I have no possibility to (let the third party) re-compile the library.

When investigating the library contents, i found that the gcc options *-ffunction-sections* and *-fdata-sections* have not been used for compiling the library. But this would be very helpful for reducing the binary size of the project.

Compilation is done with: *(GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.8.4 20140526 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 211358].*

Is there any way to put every data and every function into their own separate section to enable function-level-linking for this library, without needing to recompile code?

I thought of this possible approach:

- Split library into its object files.
- For each object file:

  - Write code to move the symbols into own sections
- Put new object files back together into archive file

Could this work, or do you have other suggestions, which ideally only use the tools provided by arm-gcc?

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware this is old, but I came across this problem as well, and figured I'd provide my findings.

**TL;DR: It's possible, but incredibly difficult. You can't simply move symbols into their own sections. Relocations will bite you.**

When the compiler generates machine code, it will generate slightly different instructions if the `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` flags are, or are not, provided. This is due to assumptions the compiler is able to make about where symbols will be located. These assumptions change depending on the flags provided.

This is best illustrated by example. Take the following very simple code snippet:

```
int a, b;

int getAPlusB()
{
    return a + b;
}
```

The following is the result of `arm-none-eabi-objdump -xdr test.o`:

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Os -mthumb -mcpu=cortexm3 -mlittle-endian -o test.o test.c`:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 g     F .text  0000000c getAPlusB
00000004 g     O .bss   00000004 b
00000000 g     O .bss   00000004 a

Disassembly of section .text:

00000024 <getAPlusB>:
  24:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (2c <getAPlusB+0x8>)
  26:   cb09        ldmia   r3, {r0, r3}
  28:   4418        add r0, r3
  2a:   4770        bx  lr
  2c:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
            2c: R_ARM_ABS32 .bss
```

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections \
  -mthumb -mcpu=cortexm3 -mlittle-endian -o test.o test.c`:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 g     F .text.getAPlusB    00000014 getAPlusB
00000000 g     O .bss.b 00000004 b
00000000 g     O .bss.a 00000004 a

Disassembly of section .text.getAPlusB:

00000000 <getAPlusB>:
   0:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (c <getAPlusB+0xc>)
   2:   6818        ldr r0, [r3, #0]
   4:   4b02        ldr r3, [pc, #8]    ; (10 <getAPlusB+0x10>)
   6:   681b        ldr r3, [r3, #0]
   8:   4418        add r0, r3
   a:   4770        bx  lr
    ...
            c: R_ARM_ABS32  .bss.a
            10: R_ARM_ABS32 .bss.b
```

The difference is subtle, but important. The flag enabled code performs two separate loads, while the disabled code performs a single "load multiple." The enabled code does this because it *knows* both symbols are contained in the same section, in a certain sequence. With the enabled code, this is not the case. The symbols are in two separate sections, and while it is likely they will keep their order and proximity, it is not guaranteed. What's more, if both sections are not referenced, the linker may decide one section is not used, and remove it.

Another example:

```
int a, b;

int getB()
{
  return b;
}
```

And the generated code. First without the flags:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 g     F .text  0000000c getB
00000004 g     O .bss   00000004 b
00000000 g     O .bss   00000004 a

Disassembly of section .text:

00000018 <getB>:
  18:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (20 <getB+0x8>)
  1a:   6858        ldr r0, [r3, #4]
  1c:   4770        bx  lr
  1e:   bf00        nop
  20:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
            20: R_ARM_ABS32 .bss
```

And with the flags:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000 g     F .text.getB 00000014 getB
00000000 g     O .bss.b 00000004 b
00000000 g     O .bss.a 00000004 a

Disassembly of section .text.getB:

00000000 <getB>:
   0:   4b01        ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; (8 <getB+0x8>)
   2:   6818        ldr r0, [r3, #0]
   4:   4770        bx  lr
   6:   bf00        nop
   8:   00000000    .word   0x00000000
            8: R_ARM_ABS32  .bss.b
```

In this case, the difference is even more subtle. The enabled code loads with an offset of 0, while the disabled code uses 4. Since the disabled code references the beginning of the section, it needs to offset to the location of `b`. However the enabled code references the section which contains solely `b`, and therefore does not need an offset. If we were to split this and only change the relocation, the new code would contain a reference to the section `a` was in, but not `b`. This, again, could cause the linker to garbage collect the wrong section.

These were just two scenarios that I came across when looking at this problem, there may be more.

Producing valid object files functionally equivalent to code compiled with the `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` flags would require parsing the machine instructions looking for these and any other relocation issues that could come up. This is not an easy task to accomplish.